# 1st order nonlinear differential equation. How could terms under fractional power be splitted in order to integrate analytically.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in solving the following $1^{st}$ order nonlinear differential equation analytically:
$$\dot{x}(t)=\left( f(t) + g(x(t)) \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}; \quad 0<n\leq1$$
where $\dot{x}(t)$ is the first derivative over $t$ of equation $x(t)$, $f(t)$ is a function of $t$ and $g(x(t))$ is a function of $x(t)$. The question is how the term in the bracket $\left( f(t) + g(x(t)) \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ can be splitted in order to be able to integrate:
$$\int dx = \int \left( f(t) + g(x(t)) \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} dt $$